# SharedPreferences editing

Tags: android

Im having problem incrementing a sharedpreference. Isn't it possible?

`..`

`SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());`
`SharedPreferences.Editor favEdit = getPrefs.edit();`
`int somepref = getPrefs.getInt("somePref", 0);`
`somepref++;`
`favEdit.putInt("somePref", somepref);`
`favEdit.commit();`

This should work imo, but when executed it's just ignored.

If i use a number instead it works fine, but then the point in using the sharedpreference is lost..

Anyone?

How I load my preferences:
`SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());`
`getPrefs = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);`
`int somepref = getPrefs.getInt("somePref", 0);`

The problem is that I want my somepref to increase in function1 @ activity1, and use the somepref to define what function to run in activity2.

The main plan:
I want to add a imagebutton from one activity to another by doing a longclick. And I want to be able add more than one imagebutton.
And from this new activity I want a longclick to remove the imagebutton.
I'm having problems getting my head around how to do this..

Comment: I don't think that code even compiles...

Comment: please make sure your code is synthetically valid, as it will hep all spot the problem.

Comment: Should be correct now. Sorry.

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you looked at the preferences XML to see if it's being updated? How are you opening the preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somepref.putInt("somePref", somepref);`

should be

`favEdit.putInt("somePref", somepref);`

and `fav.commit();` shouls be `favEdit.commit();`

and do you have `getPrefs = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);` somewhere?

Comment: and do you have `getPrefs = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0); somewhere?` is in the ".." :p

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how you compile the current code
you need to change the last two lines to

```
    favEdit.putInt("somePref", somepref);
    favEdit.commit();
```